# How to Run Scripts from the Installation Media Within an autounattend.xml file?

Tags: windows, powershell, script, automation

I've made some PowerShell (.ps1) and Batch (.bat) scripts that I would like to make part of an automated Windows installation. I have already configured everything else within my autounattend.xml file using the Windows System Image Manager and it works perfectly fine except for executing my scripts.

Before trying to go completely automated I used to enter Audit Mode (CTRL+SHIFT+F3) bypassing the OOBE and then run my scripts from there. Knowing my scripts worked in Audit Mode, within Windows System Image Manager I decided to insert synchronous commands at Pass 6 audituser.

This is my autouattend.xml file so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>cABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>3</LogonCount>
                <Username>LocalAdmin</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>cABhAHMAcwB3AG8AcgBkAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Name>LocalAdmin</Name>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName></DisplayName>
                        <Description>Local adminstrator stored on the system drive</Description>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <OOBE>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            </OOBE>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EnableNetwork>false</EnableNetwork>
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Size>500</Size>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <Size>16</Size>
                            <Type>MSR</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label></Label>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Format>FAT32</Format>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                            <Order>3</Order>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                            <Value>Windows 10 Pro</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
                    <Key />
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-gb</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-gb</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-gb</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-us</UILanguageFallback>
            <UILanguage>en-gb</UILanguage>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="auditUser">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <Path>powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File &quot;Files\Scripts\2A-Create_Daily_System_Restore_Point.ps1&quot;</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Description>Remove Windows Bloatware Provisioned Apps</Description>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File &quot;%~dp0\Files\Scripts\1-Remove_Bloatware_Apps.ps1&quot;</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <Path>cmd.exe /c %~dp0\Files\Scripts\3-Remove_Folders_from_This_PC.bat</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:d:/users/will/documents/it%20projects/windows%2010%20image/install.wim#Windows 10 Home" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

I will be placing a directory called 'Scripts' at the root of the Windows install media so my question is, how do I call these scripts in the autounattend.xml from the install media? Is there a variable that links to the drive and path where the install media is?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found the solution.

1. Extract the ISO/Windows installation media to a folder
2. Create a folder inside `sources\` directorie(s) of the extracted installation media called **$OEM$**
3. Mirror the System drive so that you have a directory with the following path `sources\$OEM$\$$\Setup\Scripts` **(C:\Windows\Setup\Scripts)**

The $OEM$ folder mirrors the system drive so anything inside these folders gets copied across during setup. In regards to the scripts being run from the autounattend.xml file, you simply have to call the scripts from `%SystemDrive%\WinDir\Setup\Scripts`

More information can be found here > https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh825027%28v%3dwin.10%29

Comment: More up-to-date information here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/distribution-shares-and-configuration-sets-overview

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the `auditUser` pass won't be executed during Windows Installation unless the system is put into Audit Mode. Hence, beside your solution, there are two other possible solutions:

1. Put your commands in the `specialize` pass or `oobeSystem` pass. Usually, the installation media would be assigned letter `X:`, but if you want to ensure that the setup would find the scripts, you can use some condition like this:

```
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Description>Run script</Description>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <!-- Enumerate through all drives looking for the MYIT_OEMBypass.ps1 script, if found, run it. Leave the command prompt open. -->
                    <Path>cmd /c "(FOR %i IN (C D E F G H I J K L N M) DO IF EXIST %i:\MYIT_OEMBypass.ps1 Powershell -executionpolicy ByPass %i:\MYIT_OEMBypass.ps1) & pause"</Path>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
```

2. Instruct the Windows Setup to run straight into Audit Mode (sysprep) when the `oobeSystem` pass starts to execute by putting this:

```
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Reseal>
                <Mode>Audit</Mode>
                <ForceShutdownNow>false</ForceShutdownNow>
            </Reseal>
        </component>
```

Using this method, you **can keep** your commands at `auditUser` pass. This also helps setting up a default profile with all your favorite tweaks, so any profile created later will also have all those tweaks applied.

However, by defaults, the **auto**unattend.xml will be copied and set as the unattend.xml script of sysprep which would obviously cause issues. So you will need to make some minor changes to instruct sysprep to use a *different* unattend.xml. A more detailed guide for this method can be found here:
https://rzander.azurewebsites.net/modern-os-deployment-mosd/